# Data Clean Up: Remove one hyphen not others

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio. I have a column of PO number in my table. The PO numbers should be a string of numbers hyphen PO hyphen last four or five characters.

So, it should look like `123456123-PO-1234`

I have some that are `123456-123-PO-1234-0`.

Is there a way I could strip out that first hyphen and last hyphen and the 0?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is no invalid data

```
declare @v varchar(20) = '123456123-PO-1234-0'
select stuff(left(@v, len(@v) -charindex('-', reverse(@v))), 
       charindex('-', @v + '-'), 1, '')
```

EDIT:

Used as a table:

```
declare @t table(v varchar(30))
insert @t values('123456123-PO-1234-0')

select stuff(left(v, len(v) -charindex('-', reverse(v))), 
       charindex('-', v + '-'), 1, '')
from @t
```